# Period difference for every column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a weird raw dataframe in pandas, which looks like:

```
class year period type info  valuebasic value1 value2 value3... value16
A     2019  16     A  bla    10         1        0     0        2
A     2019  32     A  bla    20         0        1     1        1
...
A    2021   16     A bla     30         30       1     2        1
...
B   2019    16     A bla     1          1        1     1        1
```

And I want to calculate the cumulative szn fir every class year and period for the value columns, so that I have it for the period 17-32 and so on, which ends up in the following dataframe:

```
class year period type info  value
A     2019   16   A    bla  10
A     2019   17   A  bla 11 (10+1)
A     2019   18   A bla  11 (10+1+0)
....
A     2019   32   A bla 20 (10+1+0+0+...+2)
A     2019   32   A bla  20
...
A    2021   16    A bla 30
.....
B    2019   16    A bla 1
....
B    2019   32   A bla 24 (1+1+...+1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for unpivot with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df = (df.melt(['class','year','period','valuebasic'], 
             ignore_index=False)
        .sort_index(kind='mergesort', ignore_index=True)
        .drop('variable', axis=1))
       
df['value1'] = df['valuebasic']  + df.groupby(['class','year','period'])['value'].cumsum()
print (df)
   class  year  period  valuebasic  value  value1
0      A  2019      16          10      1      11
1      A  2019      16          10      0      11
2      A  2019      16          10      0      11
3      A  2019      16          10      2      13
4      A  2019      32          20      0      20
5      A  2019      32          20      1      21
6      A  2019      32          20      1      22
7      A  2019      32          20      1      23
8      A  2021      16          30     30      60
9      A  2021      16          30      1      61
10     A  2021      16          30      2      63
11     A  2021      16          30      1      64
12     B  2019      16           1      1       2
13     B  2019      16           1      1       3
14     B  2019      16           1      1       4
15     B  2019      16           1      1       5
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = (df.set_index(['class','year','period','valuebasic'])
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=4, drop=True)
       .reset_index(name='value'))
       
df['value1'] = df['valuebasic']  + df.groupby(['class','year','period'])['value'].cumsum()
print (df)
   class  year  period  valuebasic  value  value1
0      A  2019      16          10      1      11
1      A  2019      16          10      0      11
2      A  2019      16          10      0      11
3      A  2019      16          10      2      13
4      A  2019      32          20      0      20
5      A  2019      32          20      1      21
6      A  2019      32          20      1      22
7      A  2019      32          20      1      23
8      A  2021      16          30     30      60
9      A  2021      16          30      1      61
10     A  2021      16          30      2      63
11     A  2021      16          30      1      64
12     B  2019      16           1      1       2
13     B  2019      16           1      1       3
14     B  2019      16           1      1       4
15     B  2019      16           1      1       5
```

For repalce original column `value` use:

```
df['value'] = df['valuebasic']  + df.groupby(['class','year','period'])['value'].cumsum()
```

Comment: this doesn't produce the right outcome, i include more 'class','year','period' in the array (for example: 'product, 'tpye'). so the first approach ends up with a zero dataframe and the middle dataframes doenst look correct.

Comment: the middle dataframe has some letters and so in the 'value' column

Comment: @PV8 - Can you change data sample with expected output for see problem?

Comment: I added the example above

Comment: @PV8 - So it means in some columns `value1` to `value16` is non numeric values like `A` ?

Comment: no, column value1-value16 is only numeric. but somehow he takes the columns before and puts it into the value column

Comment: @PV8 - Is possible some column was forgotten pass to `set_index` ?